# How to index a Python list in an Sympy Sum?

Tags: python, sympy

I want to compute following sum (last line of the code) in Python using Sympy:

```
# Theta Functions, n = 0, 1, ... , x
theta_n = [0]*(x+1)
sig = sy.symbols('sigma^2', real=True)
j = sy.symbols('j', integer=True)
theta_n[0] = 1
theta_n[1] = 1 
for n in range(2,x+1):
   theta_n[n] = sy.Sum( sig**j * theta_n[n-2*j], (j,1,int(n/2))).doit()
```

but I get the following error

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Add

I am a complete Sympy newbie and would like to know how to do this in the right way. One workaround would be to compute the sum with a for loop which works nice but i think isnt the right way to do it. Maybe i need a other representation for thetan or I can somehow convert j to an integer in the sum to get access to the elements of the python list.

Comment: hi, I'm not familiar with Sympy, but it appears like the 'n-2*j' in the 'theta_n[n-2*j]' is a Add object, not an integer. So the best solution is to convert the 'j' into an integer (or take the integer value associated). In that case it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried that, but it gives me the error:
TypeError: can't convert symbols to int

Comment: Hi, maybe the int function won't work directly, but have you tried, for example, using a specific attribute of 'j' that gives you its integer value. I unfortunately don't know how Sympy works, so I can't help you more.

Comment: That doesnt work unfortunately because j is symbolic dummy variable in the sum which doesnt really take all the integer values as JohanC stated in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you try to use a sympy symbol (`j`) to index into a list. List indexing only works with Python integers. In your case, you can use `j` to a normal Python integer, and use a regular Python `sum`. This regular sum will get converted first to addition and then to sympy `Add` when needed. Note that the Python range command needs one number higher than the last index.

```py
import sympy as sy

x = 12

theta_n = [0]*(x+1)
sig = sy.symbols('sigma^2', real=True)
theta_n[0] = 1
theta_n[1] = 1
for n in range(2, x+1):
    theta_n[n] = sum(sig ** j * theta_n[n - 2 * j] for j in range(1, n//2+1) )
```

Note that in the sympy expression, `sy.Sum( sig**j * theta_n[n-2*j], (j,1,int(n/2)))`, `j` is a complete symbolic variable, and `j` doesn't really take all the values one by one such as in a Python iteration.

Consider for example:

```py
print(sy.Sum(j*j, (j, 1, 1_000_000_000)).doit())
```

Sympy immediately gives the correct result (`333333333833333333500000000`) by converting the expression to `n**3/3 + n**2/2 + n/6`. This would take a long while to calculate with a regular Python summation.

Comment: You are a hero that was exactly I was looking for, thank you. I somehow thought i have access to the integer value of j but it makes sense that it is only symbolic and that Sympy first finds a expression for the sum and than plugging the boundaries of the sum in. Also this is more readable than programming a for loop for the sum.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Sum use a loop over `j`

```
for j in range(1, n//2 + 1):
    theta_n[n] += theta_n[n-2*j]*sig**j
```

These two lines replace your single line with Sum.

Once you look at the results that you are getting you might notice the pattern and rewrite the nth term as

```
>>> theta_n = lambda x: 2**max(0, x//2-1)*sig**(x//2)
>>> theta_n(100)
562949953421312*sigma^2**50
```

Comment: Thank you, I already figured that out and it gives the same result as the answer from JohanC, but using pythons sum function is better readable when going through the code.